# Add weights and correlation types in stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

Is there a way to specify weights and correlation types in ggplot2, stat_smooth function. I am trying to plot a smooth function using the following gam mode. Is there a way to specify the parameters in stat_smooth()

```
set.seed(1)
D = data.table(id = rep((1:100),10), value = rnorm(1000), stratification = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), 25))
setkey(D, id)
D = D[, time := 1:10, by = id]
w = 1/(0.1 + time)^2 
Model <- gam(formula = value~ s(time), weights=w, data=D, correlation=corAR1(form =~ time))
```

Is there a way to plot this smoothing function in ggplot2?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
set.seed(1)
D = data.table(id = rep((1:100),10), value = rnorm(1000), stratification = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), 25))
setkey(D, id)
D[, time := 1:10, by = id]
D$w = 1/(0.1 + D$time)^2 
Model <- gam(formula = value~ s(time), weights=w, data=D, correlation=corAR1(form =~ time))
pred <- data.frame(time=D$time, fitted=Model$fitted.values)
ggplot(D, aes(time, value)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=pred,aes(time, fitted), col='steelblue', lwd=1.2)
```

[image]